# how to set action property in a form to go to another form in same html page and how to get values in first form into second form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 forms in same html page.one form get the values and then these values must be pass to the second form.But I don't know how to go to the second form through the first form.

when using action="#" , I can go to same page. but how to go to the second form after get values from first form?Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form’s action property is to be used when you are sending your form data to server. In your case you can do the copying client-side (by using JavaScript) and you can omit the first *form* tag altogether.

See the example below.

```js
document.getElementById('first_form_submit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
 
 document.getElementById('second_form_input').value = document.getElementById('first_form_input').value;
 // do the same for other form fields that you need to copy
});
```

```css
.form {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="first_form" class="form">
 <input type="text" id="first_form_input" />
 <button id="first_form_submit">Send values to second form</button>
</div>

<form method="post" action="some-url" class="form">
 <input type="text" id="second_form_input" name="some_name" />
</form>
```